# How do I insert an image path quickly in markdown using sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, markdown, insert-image

I am writing some markdown file which will show some images in another directory. The directory structure is like the following:

```
D:\NUTSHARE\PERSONAL_NOTE
├─daily_note
├─images
├─misc
├─resources
└─tech_note
```

I write markdown file in one of the `daily_note`, `misc`, `resources` and `tech_note` directory and reference images in the `images` directory.

To insert image, I use the Markdown syntax: `![<IMG_DESCRITPION>](<IMG_PATH>)`. 
I wonder if there are tools or shortcut or snippet to help me to quickly insert the path of an image located in the `images` directory. Having to type the relative path every time I want to insert an image is time-wasting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching and trial and error. I have found a way to insert an image's relative path easily into Markdown file.

#### Prerequisite

We need to install two handy sublime text plugins: [MarkdownEditting](https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing) and [SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/SideBarEnhancements-org/SideBarEnhancements).

#### Insert an image path quickly

MarkdownEditting provide a snippet to type inline image quickly. Type `mdi` and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> will insert a inline image template.

Then go to the sidebar and find the image, right click on the image you want to insert and choose `Copy as Text -> Relative Path from View`. Then paste the relative path of the image onto the inline image template created before.